# Site Does Not Reflect Edits Inside Wordpress CMS

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

Anything I do inside our Wordpress CMS for some of our pages does not reflect on the actual website. It's like as if it's disconnected. The other pages are confirmed connected though.

Why is this and where should I look especially that it happens only to selected pages?

Btw, I probably should've indicated a sample of the problematic pages. Here's one: http://www.criminal-lawyers.com.au/courts/locations.

Comment: have you added any cache plugin?

Comment: @BhumiShah Can you elaborate? there are other people managing our site and I'm not always informed on recent changes. I'm sure some plugins have been added since then but the other pages are working fine and connected. What I don't get is why certain pages seem to be disconnected.

Comment: Disable your cache plugin then try changes ,it will affect.

Comment: I wonder why I got a downvote for this question. The downvoter should've probably indicated why so I can learn a lesson (and the others as well).

Answer (score 1):

Look the template of effected pages.

Take that page on admin panel on the right side of that page you can see page attribute section ,Look on the template that set for that page. It may be a static template that do not accept the content.

Just change the template to default template.

Then view that page .If content are reflected then request the developer to do that in the selected template also.

(NOTICE:entire style of the page is lost.You need to reselect to previous template and save it after seeing the change )

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually did what you suggested but still no luck. I identified a template that was confirmed working and set it to be used by the problematic page. And still the edits don't get reflected.